# How do I run Python scripts automatically, while my Flask website is running on a VPS?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, server, web-hosting

Okay, so basically I am creating a website. The data I need to display on this website is delivered twice daily, where I need to read the delivered data from a file and store this new data in the database (instead of the old data).

I have created the python functions to do this. However, I would like to know, what would be the best way to run this script, while my flask application is running? This may be a very simple answer, but I have seen some answers saying to incorporate the script into the website design (however these answers didn't explain how), and others saying to run it separately. The script needs to run automatically throughout the day with no monitoring or input from me.

TIA

Comment: I use pythonanywhere.com for my flask website. It also hosts my MySQL database. I've had no problems, and the back end python stuff is easy. Instead of 'running the flask application' python anywhere always is running. The site instead needs 'reloading' if any changes to py scripts are made (but no reload necessary for static file changes such as html and css). I am no expert in this field, but I can testify that python anywhere is working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's a really bad idea to put a webserver to handle such tasks, that is the flask application in your case. There are many reasons for it so just to name a few:

- Python's Achilles heel - GIL.
- Sharing system resources of the application between users and other operations.
- Crashes - it happens, it could be unlikely but it does. And if you are not careful, the web application goes down along with it.

So with that in mind I'd advise you to ditch this idea and use [crontabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Basically write a script that does whatever transformations or operations it needs to do and create a cron job at a desired time.

Comment: I am not familiar with crontabs but I will research it. Using these, can I reliably run the script at regular intervals every single day, without me having to manually interact with it?

Comment: @LiamWebb this has been the de-facto standard way to do such things for almost 50 years, so yes. If your script works, it will work. If the script crashes, it will run it again next time it needs to. Also thousands of ways to monitor those so yes, this is the way to go.

Comment: Okay brilliant, thankyou. Is there any special way I need to organise the python script or can I just set it up like a normal python file? ( Sorry this will be my first website I actually complete and get on a VPS so I havent used a lot of these concepts before)

Comment: The idea is that the cronjob runs on behalf of whichever user you set it up from. The requirements are: 1. The script must be executable (google `chmod`). 2. In all cases the script must include what type it is and which interpreter it should use. So in the case of python it should begin with something like `#!/usr/bin/python3` or whichever python you are using (say virtualenvironment).

Comment: Okay thankyou. I will look into it all and try to wrap my head around it :-)